# login with firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In your app create two activity for login and register, and keep trying.make sure your firebase connection is enable with your app. thanks, here code for login activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    register = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register);
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Register.class));
        }
    });

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user = username.getText().toString();
            pass = password.getText().toString();

            if(user.equals("")){
                username.setError("can't be blank");
            }
            else if(pass.equals("")){
                password.setError("can't be blank");
            }
            else{
                String url = "https://fireapp-ae761.firebaseio.com/users.json";
                final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                pd.setMessage("Loading...");
                pd.show();

                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        if(s.equals("null")){
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "user not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                                if(!obj.has(user)){
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "user not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                else if(obj.getJSONObject(user).getString("password").equals(pass)){
                                    UserDetails.username = user;
                                    UserDetails.password = pass;
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,FirebaseNewActivity.class));
                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                },new Response.ErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        System.out.println("" + volleyError);
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Login.this);
                rQueue.add(request);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

and here register activity,you must be add edit text and button in your layout for your each activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    registerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
    login = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.login);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Register.this, Login.class));
        }
    });

    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user = username.getText().toString();
            pass = password.getText().toString();

            if(user.equals("")){
                username.setError("can't be blank");
            }
            else if(pass.equals("")){
                password.setError("can't be blank");
            }
            else if(!user.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")){
                username.setError("only alphabet or number allowed");
            }
            else if(user.length()<5){
                username.setError("at least 5 characters long");
            }
            else if(pass.length()<5){
                password.setError("at least 5 characters long");
            }
            else {
                final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
                pd.setMessage("Loading...");
                pd.show();

                String url = "https://fireapp-ae761.firebaseio.com/users.json";

                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        Firebase reference = new Firebase("https://fireapp-ae761.firebaseio.com/users");

                        if(s.equals("null")) {
                            reference.child(user).child("password").setValue(pass);
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                                if (!obj.has(user)) {
                                    reference.child(user).child("password").setValue(pass);
                                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "registration successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        pd.dismiss();
                    }

                },new Response.ErrorListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        System.out.println("" + volleyError );
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
                rQueue.add(request);
            }
        }
    });
}
```